# horsepower improvement using hi test gas with turbo engine

Tags: engine, honda, accord

Will the use of "hi test" fuel yield higher horsepower for my 2018 Honda Accord 1.5 turbo engine?

The manual recommends 87 or higher.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Higher octane may result in the ability to further advance ignition timing, and will improve performance - especially on turbosupercharged engines that use a knock sensor to determine the timing base map.

Answer (score -1):

If the engine is designed for 91 or 93 and you use 87, you'll get lower performance and MPG. But if the engine is designed for 87 and you use 91 or 93, you will not get higher MPG.

Comment: The engine optimizes itself based on the knock sensors for example, so yes you will get better combustion, slightly more power and maybe better mpg...